# Read file in internal Download folder Android R

Tags: android, android-studio, android-11

on Android R i'm fine to write file in Download folder. If i try to read file i get IOException access denied.

```
zis = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +
                "/Download/saves.zip")));
```

What is the right way to read file on Android R or from what folder can i read without problem?

I'm using

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

android:requestLegacyExternalStorage=”true”
```

EDIT:
New Code

```
ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
contentValues.put(MediaStore.Downloads.DISPLAY_NAME, "saves.zip");
contentValues.put(MediaStore.Downloads.MIME_TYPE, "application/zip");
Uri uri = null;
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            uri = MediaStore.Downloads.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL);
        }
        Uri itemUri = getContentResolver().insert(uri, contentValues);

zis = new ZipInputStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(itemUri));
```

Comment: `EDIT: New Code` And?? What is it what you wanna tell about this code?

Answer (score 1):

Starting in Android 11, apps that use the scoped storage model can access only their own app-specific cache files.

So better use app's shared data folder to write/read your files.

here is the full description.

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage#permissions-target-11

Comment: I'm trying in the way i've updated in post, but now i get FileNotFound exception

Answer (score -1):

> > on Android R i'm fine to write file in Download folder.

If your app can write a file somewhere than it can certainly read that file.

Your problem does not make sense.

Is there anything you did not tell?

Comment: This is the strange thing. If i write the file (and this works in Download folder) than i can read it. But if i create manually the file with a file manager and then try to read it i got exception

Comment: Of course you have no acces then on Android 11+. Why did you fail to tell this scenario!?